# Aspose.Slides for .NET API

Tags: c#, .net, hyperlink, aspose-slides

Can anyone explain the difference between
`SetExternalHyperlinkMouseOver` and
`SetExternalHyperlinkClick`?

I am trying to add a tool tip text along with redirection hyperlink in an Aspose slide text using C#. But I'm unable to understand what the difference between `SetExternalHyperlinkMouseOver` and `SetExternalHyperlinkClick` is.

Answer (score 0):

`SetExternalHyperlinkMouseOver` sets the mouse over text shown by the PDF.

`SetExternalHyperlinkClick` however sets what url will be followed when the hyperlink is clicked.

Does that clear things up?